# What do I need to do for a forEach

Tags: javascript

Define a function, iterativeLog(), that accepts an array. Call .forEach() on this array, and inside the callback, log each element with the format ${index}: ${element}.

My code below:

```
function iterativeLog(array) {
 array.forEach(`${index}: ${element}`);
}
return iterativeLog();
```

My error code below:

1) index iterativeLog(array) logs each element with the format `${index}: ${element}`:
     ReferenceError: iterativeLog is not defined
      at Context. (test/index-test.js:6:7)

Comment: Did you check `.forEach()` documentation on MDN? It explains well how you should pass a function to `forEach` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: This seems to be a matter of reading the documentation

Comment: you need to have arguments for index and element  0_0

Comment: what is the purpose of `return iterativeLog()`?

Comment: Thank you all... I'm attempting to self-learn coding and new to this site in particular as this is my first post.

Comment: @stamps, you are in the right path, try to get through the documentation at times, it will make it easier for you to understand concepts

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding callback functions, this is the article I typically recommend students: javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/ skip the huge advertisement at the top.

Comment: @CalebJay ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will show that you can loop and access element and index as below:

```js
function iterativeLog(array) {
 array.forEach((element,index)=> console.log(`${index}: ${element}`));
}
iterativeLog([1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the **function** `Array.prototype.forEach` take as an argument? Let's look [at the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). MDN is a very good site for understanding Javascript functions.

According to MDN, `Array.prototype.forEach` expects a `function` as an argument. [Here's a ton of information on what a function is in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

```
arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg])
```

Specifically, a *callback* function. This is a common paradigm in Javascript. [Here's a helpful article on using them](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

What that `forEach` definition above is saying is:

1. `Array.prototype.forEach` expects a function to be passed to it when it is invoked
2. That function, the *callback function*, will be invoked (multiple times), and each time will be passed `currentValue` (any type), `index` (a number corresponding to `currentValue`'s location in the array), and `array`, the actual array itself.

That means that if I had the array

```
const donutArray = ['bob', 'loves', 24, 'donuts'];
```

And the function

```
const printOutMyArgument(printMe) {
    console.log(printMe);
}
```

I could invoke `Array.prototype.forEach` like so:

```
donutArray.forEach(printOutMyArgument);
```

If I did this, you would see in the console

```
'bob'
'loves'
24
'donuts'
```

Because this is what happened "under the hood."

```
printOutMyArgument('bob', 0, donutArray);
printOutMyArgument('loves', 1, donutArray);
printOutMyArgument(24, 2, donutArray);
printOutMyArgument('donuts', 3, donutArray);
```

Instead of typing that out manually, how could you accomplish the same result with a `for loop`? [For loop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: for (i = 0; i < donuts.length; i++);